# datatable tabletools excel export is picking up source code

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

I've downloaded the latest datatables and tabletools files and I'm using the export to excel and all works fine.  However, in my table I have some links where I use the "onclick" event of the div to put some javascript code in it.  When I export out the data to excel, it is picking up the source code from the "onclick" event and putting it into the spreadsheet, but when I export it to PDF it does not pickup the source code and looks as expected.  Any idea how to resolve this?  Is there a way I can tell tabletools to skip ceretain content like this?

The "onclick" event opens up a jqueryui dialog box and places data into it.

Here's a snippet of the HTML:

```
<table id="DataTables_Table_4" class="datatable_ss_1393373511 dataTable" width="100%" ">
    <thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td class=" sorting_1">
           <div style="float:left;width:100%;">
            <div class="a_link edit_link" onclick=" $('#modal_popup').attr('id','74_11120_modal_popup'); edit_this('74_11120_modal_popup', 11120, 'HTML_occupant_edit', 'SQL_SELECT_one_occupant', '', 'html.property.occupants.php', 'sql_property_occupants.php'); $('#close').hide(); $('#74_11120_modal_popup').attr('id','modal_popup'); $('#modal_popup').dialog('option','width',975).dialog('option','title', 'a Jimbo - Edit').dialog('open');" title="Edit">a Jimbo</div>

         </td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here's the output into the Excel File. It pickus up the 3 columns ("Tenant", "Property", "Accounting") just fine, but it also picked up the html from the link with the "onclick" event.  If I remove the javascript between the "onclick", then the export works as expected:

```
Tenant  Property    Accounting                      
<div title="Edit" class="a_link edit_link" onclick="                                
                                $('#modal_popup').attr('id','74_11120_modal_popup');
                                edit_this('74_11120_modal_popup', 11120, 'HTML_occupant_edit', 'SQL_SELECT_one_occupant', '', 'html.property.occupants.php', 'sql_property_occupants.php');
                                $('#close').hide();
                                $('#74_11120_modal_popup').attr('id','modal_popup');
                                $('#modal_popup').dialog('option','width',975).dialog('option','title', 'a Jimbo - Edit').dialog('open');">a Jimbo
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the table well-formed? There is no </table> in your example.
Also, can you move the jquery code out of the html and into the head, as there's a chance that isn't well-formed either